# What is the simplest / most elegant way to passively select power supply based on voltage levels?

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, mains

I have a problem and my thinking seems to be a bit stuck.

I want to design a power supply that works on both mains voltage (120VAC to 240VAC) and voltages below 24V (AC or DC). There's only a single 2 wire input for all input voltages. The user should, however, not be bothered selecting the correct input voltage range.

I have some ideas, all of them not being very elegant and kind of a red neck way of doing things, so maybe one of you guys and gals have some inspiration for me.

The output voltage should be at 5V DC.  The power of the device connected will not exceed 5W.

Since footprint size is limited and the power supply will be housed in a potted container (German "Schutzklasse 2"), the supply should be transformerless.

Any ideas or tips - maybe someone had similar problems or experiences?

Comment: Flyback with two primary (240 and 24V), every winding has single switch, drive them according supply voltage so one of winding/switch is always off.

Comment: Can you design a mains input (or auto-switchable) power supply that you are sure it will pass required safety and electrical codes of all the countries you need to sell the device? If not, simply have 5V input and tell customers to select either mains to 5V supply or 24V to 5V supply.

Comment: Are there in the house electricity distribution system some connectors which are commonly known as low voltage outlets, for ex. to output 12V DC or AC, but some of them are actually wired to output 120 or 240 volts AC instead? I'm afraid such wiring is illegal and voids your insurances. If you design to make fixed wiring installations easier for non-electricians I suggest: FORGET IT!

Comment: (continued) Schutzklasse 2 transformerless (not even a ferrite transformer) power supply cannot in practice have a touchable output . Maybe you should reveal more to stop comments like these two

Comment: @EdHalfsunk you are right, more details might be necessary: The power supply will mainly run on 230V AC mains voltage at 50Hz. In some cases however, the device should work in circuits other than mains (mainly 12V AC but also 8V AC and 24V DC) that is found in German houses for door openers or intercoms. Regarding your second comment: The output will not be touchable. Rather, the supply will be part of a completely closed system, which is then rated at Schutzklasse 2.

Comment: @Justme indeed. Mains input power supplies are not new to me and I am certified in the field. However, since the whole "auto switching" based on voltage levels is somewhat new to me, I thought I would make use of experts on this platform.

Comment: Does the voltage change suddenly in already connected wires? I'm afraid this will happen - there can happen a brownout which stops sooner or later and then there's again the full mains AC. Is there some reason why it's impossible to connect the power feeding wires to different inputs depending on the nominal voltage?

Comment: @EdHalfsunk No, hence to the regulations in place, the voltage will not change in already connected wires. The 12VAC conductors are simply not rated for mains voltage. So that will not be a problem. Regarding the usage of different inputs - compatibility with an already existing system is the main reason for that.

Comment: @EdHalfsunk a single 2 wire input for all voltages

Comment: `details might be necessary` Edit them into the question body! And please don't use the likes of *Edit: * - there is a revision history accessible to "everyone".

Comment: If you really want to jump into calamity, you may want to extend the working concept of the MPS chip MP103.